# How to use variables in postgres script?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create a variable in postgres using `WITH` command, but I am having troubles with the scope.

If I write this code, it works fine:

```sql
WITH ids AS (
   SELECT case.id FROM case
)
select * from case where case.id in( SELECT * FROM ids);
```

But if I try next sentence I get an error

> ERROR: relation "ids" does not exist

```
WITH ids AS (
   SELECT case.id FROM case
)
COPY (SELECT * FROM case where case.id in( SELECT * FROM ids)) To '/tmp/cases.csv' WITH CSV DELIMITER ',';
```

I need to put some logic to export data to a csv file. In the future I want to filter the "ids" variables by timestamp and execute several operations with these ids (export csv is just one operation). That is why I want to create variables.

Answer (score 0):

`COPY` cannot be used after `WITH`:

```sql
WITH foo AS (SELECT 'foo')
COPY (SELECT * FROM foo) to '/tmp/data.txt';
```

This results in an error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COPY"

You can put `WITH` inside the parenthesis of the `COPY`:

```sql
COPY (
    WITH foo AS (SELECT 'foo')
    SELECT * FROM foo
) to '/tmp/data.txt';
```

But I don't think that helps with your requirement. I'm afraid that what you're trying to accomplish is not possible, you cannot perform multiple operations like that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have a solution by now.While @fphilipe is correct that 'Copy cannot be used after With' the reverse is not true. With can be used after Copy.
The output format for copy in "Copy select ... to file" and With is defined as part of select. So the following is valid: (You indicated filtering on a timestamp, so I just used created_dttz and greater that 30 days old.)

```
copy (with clist as 
         (select id 
            from case 
           where created_dttz < now()-interval '30 days'
         )
      select * from case where id in(select id from clist)
     ) 
to 'c:/cases.csv' with csv delimiter ',';
```

But even that much is not necessary, just filter in the where clause. I would opt for the much simpler but equivalent

```
copy (
      select * from case where created_dttz < now()-interval '30 days'
     ) 
to 'c:/cases2.csv' with csv delimiter ',';
```

Now editorializing (IMO) Case is a very poor and dangerous name for a table. Case is a Postgres and SQL Standard reserved word. Even if Postgres figures how you're using it, will you or another developer do so when solving a later problem? But you're free to play with fire.